# Android ActionBarCompat, action bar doesn't display correctly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, compatibility

[image: screenshot]

I am using android.support.v7 library for action bar support on old devices and android.support.v4 for fragment support.

My application on version Android 2.* doesn't display ActionBar correctly, it stretched to fill the screen and frame layout doesn't showing. ActionBarDrawerToggle button clickable, but it doesn't do anything.

There are no errors or warnings shown in the LogCat output.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In MainActivity:

```
...
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

...
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
...
```

MainActivity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main list content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define android:orientation on your DrawerLayout component. 
Are you making changes to ActionBar in your Activity code?

Comment: I added orientation parameter and commented almost all onCreate method:

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(getLayoutResId()); }`

Nothing has changed with actionbar displaying :(

Comment: Did you try do define your theme only in your activity on the manifest.xml?

Comment: set android:gravity="center" on your DrawerLayout and see if it solves the problem. In a device with higher API level, does it work?

Comment: All the same with `<activity android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >` ...

Comment: Could you show the rest of your MainActivity code?

Comment: DrawerLayout gravity="center" doesn't affect. In a device with higher API level it work normally (http://s28.postimg.org/7cwndw371/Screenshot_2014_03_30_16_08_40.png). All the same even I comment all methods, except onCreate method in MainActivity (http://pastebin.com/Y9TFYep0).

Comment: Your code is running ok, even on 2.* devices. In which device are you testing?
Try to clean your project and rerun it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing v4 jar support library from "libs" folder and removing v7 support library folder, which has been imported from eclipse project and adding this to build.gradle file in dependencies section:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0+"
```