# Android ActionBar using the whole screen... why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I followed this [simple Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) to add an *ActionBar* to incorporate with my *Drawer*, however for some reason the *ActionBar* fills up the whole screen and I can't figure out what's the problem. [This guy seems to have the exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743527/android-actionbarcompat-action-bar-doesnt-display-correctly) but his 4 years old solution doesn't apply to my case.

[image]

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- ActionBar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <!-- Main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_window"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categories_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/brightDrawerBackground"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In case the layout file is not enough, here are the files at this stage (commit c5d31ed2e6):
[MainActivity](https://github.com/NaturalBornCamper/DirectUnitConverter/blob/c5d31ed2e6c60b5d4b28f7e009594beecbda6380/app/src/main/java/com/naturalborncamper/android/directunitconverter/MainActivity.java)
[layout_main](https://github.com/NaturalBornCamper/DirectUnitConverter/blob/c5d31ed2e6c60b5d4b28f7e009594beecbda6380/app/src/main/res/layout/layout_main.xml)
[Whole project](https://github.com/NaturalBornCamper/DirectUnitConverter/tree/c5d31ed2e6c60b5d4b28f7e009594beecbda6380)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436350/1576416

Comment: If the Toolbar is put into a full screen Linear/Relative/etc Layout inside the DrawerLayout, it should show as expected.

Comment: Demonick is correct. Move the `Toolbar` to inside the `LinearLayout`. You should have only one content `View` – i.e., only one non-drawer `View` –
 directly inside the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I wish Google specified it was mandatory to have only 2 child in a DrawerLayout from this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html or the DrawerLayout page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Comment: It's not really mandatory to have only two child `View`s in a `DrawerLayout`. You can have two drawers, one on either side. Also, you actually _can_ have more than one content `View`, but for most designs, one is sufficient. Just FYI.